# Provide library from Eclipse plugin to workspace

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

JUnit does the same, and I just can't figure out how...

[image: Eclipse junit quick fix]

I guess thats because of this entry in the Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library wizard:

[image: Eclipse junit add library]

How can I do the same and include my library in this wizard from my plugin, i.e. make it available to a user in workspace?

Comment: Did you managed to get it working? I'm trying the same, but only by extending the mentioned in the answers extension points, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Yes, it's working now. I consulted a lot of JUnit source code, copied and adjusted parts. You can look at my code here (either under "Source Code" or install the plugin, it contains source code as well): http://scg.unibe.ch/wiki/projects/DoodleDebug

The most important classes are in the folder `DoodleServer` in the packages `ch.unibe.scg.doodle.server.buildpath` and `ch.unibe.scg.doodle.server.quickfix`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Offtopic: Btw nice work with Doo.dle

Comment: Offtopic: Thx, feel free to use it and ask questions on SO if you have... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there are three different extension points you need to look at. The easiest way is to look at the JUnit plugin itself (there are four)

```
org.eclipse.jdt.junit: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.git
org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core.git
org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime.git
org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime.git
```

So, you can investigate the JUnit plugins, but these are the extension points you'll need:

For the Add Library, look at the extension point [`org.eclipse.jdt.ui.classpathContainerPage`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_classpathContainerPage.html). From the JUnit plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.classpathContainerPage">
  <classpathContainerPage
        name="%JUnitContainerName"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.buildpath.JUnitContainerWizardPage"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER">
  </classpathContainerPage>
</extension>
```

So this is implemented as `JUnitContainerWizardPage`. This extends `IClasspathContainerPage` and `IClasspathContainerPageExtension`.

For the quickfix and classpathfix see the extension points [org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_quickFixProcessors.html) and [org.eclipse.jdt.ui.classpathFixProcessors](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_classpathFixProcessors.html). From the JUnit plugin.xml again:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.quickFixProcessors">
  <quickFixProcessor
        name="%junitQuickFixProcessor"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.JUnitQuickFixProcessor"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUnitQuickFixProcessor">
  </quickFixProcessor>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.classpathFixProcessors">
  <classpathFixProcessor
        name="%junitClasspathFixProcessor"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.ui.JUnitClasspathFixProcessor"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUnitClasspathFixProcessor">
        <overrides id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.correction.DefaultClasspathFixProcessor">
        </overrides>
  </classpathFixProcessor>
</extension>
```

Comment: You, Sir, deserve a medal. It's not quite working yet, but I'm looking forward to it now... =)
Btw, I'm Swiss too, it's for a Bachelor project at the University of Berne. :D

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the extension points that are already mentioned in the thread:

The logic that initializes the container is in org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core plugin.

```
   <extension
      point="org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathContainerInitializer">
      <classpathContainerInitializer
            class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.buildpath.JUnitContainerInitializer"
            id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER">
      </classpathContainerInitializer>
   </extension>
```